# R - Filtering rows (keeping all the data between two values)

Tags: r

I am new to using R and have a question regarding the filtering of data. I have a rather big .csv file with data stored in several rows and columns.

One row contains steps numbers, where I am interested in the steps from 600 and to 700. It might happen that between 600 and 700 appear lower numbers (like 5, 10, 20 etc.).

I tried:
    `data_interest <- subset(data, data$step >=600 & data$step <=700)`

This returns only the data for the step numbers from 600 to 700. I would like to start the "saving sequence" when step number 600 appears and end it when step number 700 shows up (including the lower steps numbers which might appear in between).

I hope someone can help. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_interest = data[which(data$step >= 600)[1]:which(data$step >= 700)[1], ]
```

With `which( condition )[1]` you can obtain the index of the first matching element to your condition. And with the above code, you will get all elements between first occurance of a step number higher than 600, until 700.

Example:

```
data = data.frame(step = c(5, 6, 600, 2, 700, 3, 4, 5))

data_interest = data[which(data$step >= 600)[1]:which(data$step >= 700)[1], ]

print(data_interest)  
[1] 600   2 700
```

Edit: If there are more than one interval, the following for loop will do it.

```
data = data.frame(step = c(5,6,600,2,700,3,4,5,600,10,700,3,4,5))
current_status <- F
select_vec = rep(F, nrow(data))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$step[i] >= 600){
    current_status <- T 
  }
  select_vec[i] <- current_status
  if(current_status & data$step[i] >= 700){
    current_status <- F
  }
}
data_interest <- data[select_vec,]   

print(data_interest)
[1] 600   2 700 600  10 700
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very helpful! In my case, the sequence (step 600 to 700) occurs several times and I would like to get each one. Do you have an idea how I can solve that? Maybe with a for-loop?

Comment: @Jael I've updated the answer to include this case as well.